# What's the etymology of `ir de compras`?

Tags: modismos, etimología

In my little Spanish learning experience, I have often read the sentence that uses the term `ir de compras`. While I know the meaning of it (go to shopping), I have a trouble in getting the etymology of it.

Why does it uses the form used in second-person singular? For example, we use `dormir` in `Leo un libro antes de dormir.`, even if the verb is used after `de`. We don't write it as `Leo un libro antes de duermes.`. But it is not the case in the `ir de compras`.

So why does it always use the second-person singular form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the second person singular form of the verb *comprar*, it's the plural form of the noun *compra* (purchase), though that ultimately derives from the been *comprar*. Many nouns in Spanish derive from present tense forms of verbs, but then follow noun gender and number rules.

Comment: Thanks. Then why `ir de viaje`, not `ir de viajes`? Is there any norm like when to use plural and when to use singular?

Comment: @Gardecolo you can ir de viajes, but it's not common (generally you leave for what is seen as a single trip). Likewise, there's not a per se restriction on ir de compra, but you don't normally go out shopping for a single item, the idea of going shopping is to get multiple things.